# How to print array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I've written this code in Java that takes as input a number of integers and insert integers in the array and print the array. The problem is that output print all 0.

```
public class Array2 {
    private static int i;
    private static int[] vett ;
    private static int num2;
    private static int n;



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


     InputStreamReader In = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
     BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(In); 
     String stringa = new String();

     String s="";

     System.out.println("Enter the number of integers:");
     n = Integer.parseInt(myInput.readLine());  

      vett=new int[n];

              for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                  System.out.println("Insert integer:");
                  num2 = Integer.parseInt(myInput.readLine());  
                  s=s+vett[i]+" ";

        }  
               System.out.println(s);

 }



 }
```

run:

```
Enter the number of integers:
2
Insert integer:
1
Insert integer:
2
0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing your `num2` variable into your array.

Try

```
vett[i] = num2;
```

after you have read your `num2` value from the input stream.

BTW, to simply print the array in order to check its contents, you can use

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(vett));
```

You do not need to use a separate String to track the array contents.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to *actually* putting the numbers  into the Array:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   System.out.println("Insert integer:");
   num2 = Integer.parseInt(myInput.readLine());  
   vett[i] = num2;    // <-- this line here
   s=s+vett[i]+" ";   // and just an info: this is the same as s+=vett[i]+" ";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually doing anything with `num2`, you need something like

```
vett[i] = num2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot the following line:

```
vett[i] = num2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you print array in Java

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // where array is vett[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `num2` to `vet[i]`. By default it's value is zero if you don't assign value.

```
vett[i] = num2;
s=s+vett[i]+" ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually doing anything with num2, you need something like

```
vett[i] = num2;
```

And u can print it by using this statement

```
   `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`
```

// where array is vett[i]